# Amazon Redshift Date Comparison

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am getting an error "Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Amazon Redshift tables." and I am unsure as to why and couldn't find any support anywhere else.

I am trying to filter or delete rows where the current date is after a certain date.  I've created a very simple example.

Table "tmp" has one column "date" with one row with the value '2016-01-01'.

I want to delete the row, because it is a date that is in the future.

So my query would be:

```
DELETE FROM "tmp" WHERE TO_DATE((NOW()),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') < "date";
```

However I get the error:

> "Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Amazon Redshift tables."

I also tried casting the "date" column to DATE datatype but same error.

I also tried the function ["DATE_CMP"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_CMP.html) to do a BOOLEAN comparison

```
SELECT DATE_CMP((TO_DATE(NOW(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')),"date"::DATE), "date" 
FROM "tmp"
```

but that produced the same error.

Could someone help me out with why this is?  The only thing I can find in Redshift documentation is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_sql-functions-leader-node.html) but it doesn't seem to really mention anything relevant.

Answer (score 2):

`to_date(now(), ...)` makes no sense. `now()` **is** already a `date` there is no need to convert it to one.

The condition "*where the current date is after a certain date*" can be written as:

```
delete from tmp
where current_date > "date";
```

All date functions are documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html

---

<sup>`date` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it is also a keyword, but more importantly it does not document what the column contains. A start date? An end date? A due date? A visit date? An invoice date?</sup>